# Connection to Dynamics CRM throwing "The request was aborted: The request was canceled." exception

Tags: c#, windows-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm developing a Windows service that reads CSV files and adds records to Dynamics CRM 2011 using the `service.create()` method. It throws the following exception and I've been unable to determine why:

```
Exception Message: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Inner Exception:

Date Time: 3/14/2016 1:15:56 PM

Stack Trace:    at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Flush()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Serialize(SoapClientMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at myServ.CrmSdk.CrmService.Execute(Request Request)
   at myServ.myServ.DeleteReceiptsByRecpDate(DateTime dtToday, String AbcAgency, CrmService service)
   at myServ.myServ.timer1_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Can you post your code? The exception alone is probably not sufficient to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The OrganizationService is a WCF service in the end ... and you have the benefits of an On-Premise deployment so, maybe you're sending a request which is too big or maybe CRM is busy to be able to reply to your request before the timeout.

Anyway, you might want to consider increasing the timeout values in the Binding config.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely caused by connect timeout.
For asynchronous operations WCF will not throw TimeoutException on connect timeout. Instead it will throw CommunicationException with inner exception WebException with Status WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled.

On response timeout TimeoutException is thrown for synchronous and asynchronous operations.